# Not getting password input field while other field is I am getting, On submitting form ReactJS/HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms

I have a form for user registration. I am entering data in input fields and when I am trying to submit the form I am getting the name input field value, but undefined for the password input field

This is my Re

```
const Register = () => {
  const registerAction = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     console.log(e.target.email.value);
     console.log(e.target.password);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={registerAction}>
        <div className={classes.container}>
          <hr />

          <label for="email">
            <b>Email</b>
          </label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required />
          <label for="psw">
            <b>Password</b>
          </label>
          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Enter Password"
            name="psw"
            required
          />
          <button className={classes.registerbtn}>Register</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

This is my register form looks like, I know I am bad at styling

[image]

And my console output shows -

[image]

Here I don't know why am I getting password undefined?
I want to store the email and password in my database to register the user.

Comment: add .value property ! `console.log(e.target.password.value);`

Comment: Voted to close because of small typographical error.

Comment: Hi @monim, There was a little typo error, the name attribute of the input field was typed wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use console.log(e.target.psw.value). You are using incorrect name of password input.

```js
const registerAction = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     console.log(e.target.email.value);
     console.log(e.target.psw.value);
  };
```

Comment: When you copy "form" from a different source!! Sorry buddy, I didn't notice that and thank you _/\_